# Recuperar valor em localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde! Estou criando uma aplicação em JavaScript utilizando localstorage para o armazenamento de dados. A aplicação é simples, estou apenas praticando alguns conceitos, e nela envolve alguns dados pessoais e um campo composto de 10 números como identificação única, gerada ao cadastrar. O que estou com dificuldades em criar é uma função que busque por essa identificação única em meio aos dados salvos no localstorage.

```
function pesquisarAluno(){
let matriculas = Array()
let id = localStorage.getItem('id')
for(let i = 1; i <= id; i++){
    let recuperar_matricula = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(i))
    if(recuperar_matricula === null){
        continue
    }
    recuperar_matricula.id = i
    matriculas.push(recuperar_matricula)
}
console.log(matriculas)
```

}

Comment: E qual é a dificuldade? Qual a estrutura dos dados salvos?

Comment: No momento eu estou conseguindo passar os dados para uma array, porém eu não estou conseguindo recuperar nenhum cadastro com base na matrícula. Basicamente é recuperar um registro por meio dessa identificação.

Answer (score 0):

Para se trabalhar com Storage você precisa definir seu no seu Storage os dados e em seguida poderá recuperar os dados.

para se definir um local Storage você pode fazer como abaixo:

```
localStorage.setItem("alunos", JSON.stringify(DADOS));
```

para recuperar você pode utilizar

```
localStorage.getItem("alunos")
```

sua pergunta não foi bem definida, tenta descrever melhor seu problema.

um exemplo de um código de trabalho com storage, eu apliquei dentro de um arquivo html para ter condições de executar em um navegador.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" 
 />
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // defino um array de obetos
  const alunos = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: "Fulano de Tal Tal Tal",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nome: "Beltrado de Tal Tal Tal",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      nome: "Melano de Tal Tal Tal",
    },
  ];

  // defino o storage
  const defineStorage = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("alunos", JSON.stringify(alunos));
  };

  // executo a função
  defineStorage();

  // defino uma função de recuperação do storage
  const recebeStorage = () => {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("alunos"));
  };
  // converto em um array para trabalhar com map, filter ou outros ajudadores dos arrays
  const storage = Array.from(recebeStorage());

  // função para filtro
  const id = (id) => id.id === 2;
  
  // aplicando a função e imprimindo no console
  console.log(storage.filter(id));
  
</script>
```

Comment: Eu realmente estou emperrado nessa questão de storage. Seu eu aplicar um console logo após o loop, eu consigo puxar os ID no array, o que eu quero é puxar um dado específico dentro desse array, entende? Está complicado

Comment: não corte caminho, entenda tudo de array, em seguida você verá o quanto isso é fácil. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array